# An elegant way to create an instance of monadic stack of State and IO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats

Is there a better way to create an instance of `StateT[IO, S, A]` in the `Impl` object?

**Edit: I have edited it, it looks good to me now, can we do better?**

```
  case class BusinessState()

  trait BusinessResult
  case object KeepGoing extends BusinessResult
  case object StopNow extends BusinessResult

  type IOState[S, A] = StateT[IO, S, A]
  type BusinessIOState[A] = IOState[BusinessState, A]

  trait SomeSteps {
    def step1:BusinessIOState[Unit]
    def step2:BusinessIOState[BusinessResult]

    def program = for {
      _ <- step1
      businessResult <- step2
    } yield businessResult

  }

  object Impl extends SomeSteps {
    override def step1: BusinessIOState[Unit] = StateT { businessState =>
      //do some processing
      IO.pure((businessState, Unit))
    }
    override def step2: BusinessIOState[BusinessResult] = StateT { businessState =>
      //do some processing
      IO.pure((businessState, KeepGoing))
    }
  }

  println(Impl.program.run(BusinessState()).unsafeRunSync())
```

Comment: The question is kind of vague and as it's written now is a better fit for the Code Review Stack Exchange. It seems like you might be asking whether this is the best way to create a `StateT[IO, S, A]` from an `A`, in which case the answer is yep, you can use `StateT.empty` for `step1` and `StateT.pure(KeepGoing)` for `step2`.